# How to make three cells in one cell in a table

Tags: html, html-table

I wrote this code:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    }

    </style>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> a </td>
    <td> b </td>
    <td> c </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> a </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td> c </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> a </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td> c </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This produces a table that looks like this:

```
----------------------------------
|a       |     b      |     c    |
----------------------------------
|a       |            |     c    |
----------------------------------
|a       |            |     c    |
----------------------------------
```

But what I want is a table structure like this:

```
----------------------------------
|a       |     b      |     c    |
----------            ------------
|a       |            |     c    |
----------            ------------
|a       |            |     c    |
----------------------------------
```

Where the rows in the middle column are merged.  How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the attribute `rowspan` for the `td` with the b inside.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td rowspan="3">b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can then add CSS to adjust it to the way you like it:

```
table {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/sntgoy5d/

If you want to have the b at the top of the cell, you can use the css property `vertical-align` and set it to `top`.

Comment: You'll probably want to add `style="vertical-align: top"` to the `td` you're putting the `rowspan="3"` on.

Comment: @P.Gearman Haha yeah I was editing the post to add it as a comment.

Comment: Well, you beat me to answering the question (and far better than I would have), so it's all good. :P